# delay playing animated gif in PowerPoint

Tags: gif, microsoft-powerpoint

I have an animated gif that plays once (no loop). In PowerPoint, I want it to play when it appears on the slide, on a click.  Right now, it seems to play before it appears.  Is there a way to delay playing it until it appears?

Comment: 30 second Google search using your *exact* question title found [THIS](http://www.technologytrish.co.uk/Animated%20Gifs%20in%20Powerpoint.html) as the second result. Seems credible, but I've never done it.

Comment: Thanks for this link.  I didn't see that in my search results.  It's a crafty technique, but I can't have it happen on click of a specific image.

Comment: Seems the first slide of that sample presentation does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: It does, but it's for a presentation and when the speaker is up at the podium, the clicker sends a signal for "next slide," not "clicked a specific image on the slide."  Subtle but critical difference.

Comment: You could modify the gif so that the first frame displays for a set amount of time, long enough for the slide to fully draw in.

Comment: Unfortunately, at least in 2021, the technique listed by @Scott does not delay the start of the GIF while it is not visible. It seems to start playing (and looping, if it loops) as soon as the slide is loaded, even if the GIF image is not currently visible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I realize that this answer is coming long after the question was asked, but hopefully, it will help somebody someday...

What you can simply do is duplicate the original slide, and place your animated gif ONLY in the second slide. The second slide will appear on a click (anywhere), and the gif will automatically begin playing as that second slide is loaded. Although the slide is duplicated, it appears to the audience as a single slide.

If you want the image of the gif to be continuously displayed prior to the animation, a la the Bart Simpson in the previous example, then you can insert a still image in the first slide in the same place as the animation will appear.

Note that you might have to make other small modifications. For example, if you have some objects which you want to appear as if they are on the same slide as the animated gif, and which themselves are animated, for example, to fade in, prior to the gif being animated, you need to remove the animation from these objects on the duplicated slide, so that they do not fade in for a second time.

Comment: I up[vote because this does seem like the simplest (and certainly a well-working) approach. As with all things regarding Office, I sure hope someone finds and posts a same-slide more direct approach, but I know there isn't likely one...

Comment: Apparently, Powerpoint thinks it's 1986 and looping animated GIFs have not been invented yet.

Comment: man, you are a genius

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue – needing to fade in the GIF at some point in the slide, and for it to only start playing at that point (i.e. that click).  I am only allowed 3 slides for my interview presentation – so having extra slides does not work for me.  So...

ANOTHER SOLUTION: I converted my GIF into an MP4, and then you can start the video with a click using animations.  Easy!  I used [this](https://ezgif.com/gif-to-mp4) website to convert the GIF:

Comment: I did not remove the link

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I just want my GIF to start playing when the specific slide is active.

I found a simple way to solve it, which is upload your GIFs to google drive, then insert the gif into the slide, then it will only begin to play when the slide is actived.

Hope it helps!